# I'm worried about fitting into armrest

Tags: seating

I'm quite a big guy and I'm travelling to Benidorm and worried I won't fit in the seat when the armrest goes down. Shall I just buy another seat to save hassle when on the plane ?

Comment: It's fitting between armrests that most people aim for ;)

Answer (score 2):

Can you measure your width? Some people are wider at the hip and some people are wider at the shoulder. The typical width of short haul economy seats are about 17-18". If you're on an airline with so-called business class, in Europe this is typically the same seat but with the middle seat left free. In that case you could raise the armrest and have some more room.

Seat width for various aircraft of various airlines can be sean on [seatguru](http://seatguru.com) amongst other places.

It certainly is possible to buy an extra seat on most airlines, and in some cases it costs less than buying two full seats since you won't normally be paying some/most of the taxes at least.

Comment: It's only a small aircraft we are going on but my companion I'm traveling with said she doesn't mind the armrest being up in the middle. Does the armrest have to come down if I'm sitting with some one ?

Comment: The armrest is supposed to be down for takeoff and landing. When in flight it can go up even if the seatbelt sign is on.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain with all these quistions, but what happens if the armrest can not go down ?  As I'm slightly bigger then 17 -18 " we have decided to book an extra seat

Comment: If the arrmest can't go down, and your seat neighbour doesn't object, it's unlikely that the cabin crew will object. If you do buy two seats, you almost certainly have to call the airline; you can't just buy two seats in your own name as one of them can potentially be given away when the "other one" doesn't board.